# Prolog. Structure(complex term) vs predicate, i dont really get the difference

Tags: prolog

I'm new to prolog and i cant seem to understand the difference between a structure and a predicate.
Is there really any difference?

While digging around i found that some people consider
**f(X):-a(X)**  to be a predicate and some consider
**jealous(X,Y):-loves(X,Z),  loves(Y,Z)**  to be a structure (or a complex term). They look pretty much the same to me.

Somebody care to explain?

Comment: Syntactically, the only difference is where the term occurs. If it occurs on the top, it is interpreted as a rule, but if it occurs as an argument, it is a term.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Prolog, a *term* is a constant, atom, variable, or *compound term*.

A *compound term* consists of a *functor* with 1 or more *arguments*. The following are *terms*:

```
a.          % a term with functor 'a' and 0 arguments
a(b,c).     % a term with functor 'a' and 2 arguments, b and c
```

The empty list `[]` is *term* and, more specifically, an *atom*. A list `[H|T]` is represented intrinsically as `'.'(H, T)` and is, therefore a *compound term* and, therefore, also a *term*.

You can also have more complex *compound terms*:

```
a(b(c,d), e(f,g(h)))
```

Here, `a` is a functor with two arguments: `b(c,d)`, and `e(f,g(h))`, and so on.

A *compound term* can also be called a *structure* as they give you a way to structure facts:

```
customer(name(john,doe), address(street('123 Main St'), city('Framusville'), ...), ...).
```

A *predicate clause* is a specific *structure* or *term*. In Prolog, everything is a *structure* or *term* of the form: `functor(arg1, arg2, ...)`.

Let's look at the predicate clause:

```
f(X) :- a(X).
```

It is itself a *structure* which internally is represented as this *term*: `:-(f(X), (a(X)))`. The period (`.`) is a terminator. What makes it a *predicate*, as @false indicates, is:

- It's at the "top level" (not an argument in a higher level term)
- It's functor is `:-`

A *predicate clause* is also referred to as a *rule* since the the term, `:-(A, B)` defines the *relation*: *`A` is true if `B` is true*. The term `f(X)` is referred to as the *head* of the predicate clause.

A collection of one or more *predicate clauses* which all have the same *functor* and *arity* (number of arguments) for their heads is referred to as a *predicate*.

Looking at your second example:

```
jealous(X,Y) :- loves(X,Z), loves(Y,Z).
```

This is also one *predicate clause* for the *predicate* `jealous/2` (the *predicate* whose functor is `jealous` and has arity of 2). It would internally be expressed as this *compound term*: `:-(jealous(X,Y), ','(loves(X,Z), loves(Y,Z)))`. This means that the above expression is also a *compound term*.

You can see how Prolog views an expression in its canonical form by using `write_canonical/1`:

```
| ?- write_canonical((jealous(X,Y) :- loves(X,Z), loves(Y,Z))).
:-(jealous(_17,_18),','(loves(_17,_22),loves(_18,_22)))
```

The SWI Prolog site has a very good [glossary of Prolog terms](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=glossary).

Comment: It would be worth to edit your answer with the distinction between a *predicate* and a predicate *clause*. Both in the question and in the answer, references to *predicate* are really references to *predicate clauses*. Notably, predicates define relations but predicate clauses define parts of relations. The distinction is only mute when a predicate is defined by a single clause.

Comment: @PauloMora indeed I had already considered editing for that distinction. I just wasn't sure how far to take the discourse on terminology relative to the original question, which seemed more focused on the structure aspect. But, I updated the answer. It's an important distinction, so thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Excellent post, answered all the questions I had concerning this topic! However, it raised a new question: What is about the ````,````? It seems to be used ambiguously in Prolog: Once as a functor for a structure, which contains multiple literals, and once for separating the elements of a structure. ````:-(jealous(X,Y), ','(loves(X,Z), loves(Y,Z)))````

Comment: @NiklasPeter, yes I think `,` has two roles. One is an operator, so that if you do `write_canonical((a,b,c))` you get `','(a,','(b,c))`. In this context, Prolog interprets `,` as a logical conjunction. But if you do `write_canonical(a(b,c))` you get `a(b,c)`. So `a(b,c)` is using `,` simply as an argument separator. In fact, even the results of both of these queries illustrates the duality of `,` since `','(a,','(b,c))` uses the comma in both roles.

Comment: Thanks again. Do you know what the additional pair of parentheses around ````a, b, c```` means? Yes, of course, if you removed it, ````write_canonical```` would fail, because it received 3 arguments ````a````, ````b```` and ````c````, but I do not know what these parentheses are defined to do. Canonical form of ````(a, b, c)```` is ````','(a,','(b,c))```` and canonical form of ````(a; b; c)```` is ````;(a,;(b,c))````. Are the parentheses only for grouping the operands and the infix operator ````,```` respectively ````;````?

Comment: @NiklasPeter You need the parentheses for `write_canonical((a,b,c))` to treat `a,b,c` as a single expression or term. This is unnecessary if you have, for example, a predicate clause, `h :- p1, p2, p3` since the precedence of operators works as desired, although there's nothing wrong wit writing `h :- (p1, p2, p3).`. But without them in the `write_canonical/1` call, it looks to Prolog like you're calling `write_canonical` with 3 arguments instead of one.