# Prolog: syntactically correct objects + relation vs. structure

Tags: syntax, prolog

I'm new to Prolog and gradually working my way through Ivan Bratko's 'Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence' (4th ed.).

When doing exercise 2.1. (page 39), I fail to see why `5(X,Y)` is syntactically not correct, while `+(north,west)` is correct. At first I thought it had to do with the fact that the functor is a number (as I thought this could only be an atom), but according to the book, an atom can also be a digit. I then thought it was a problem with the arguments being variables, but I fail to see why this would pose a problem for the syntactical correctness. Could anyone point me in the right direction of an explanation?

Furthermore I was wondering what the exact difference is between a relation and a structure. While `date(1, may, 2001)` (on page 35) is seen as a structure, I was wondering if we can say the same about earlier examples from chapter 1. Is, for example, the relation `parent(pam,bob)` from the first chapter also a so-called structure, or am I confusing things?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `atom(5)` fails. So technically a number is not an atom. I don't have that particular book, so it would be interesting to know the context of their claim that *an atom can also be a digit*.

Comment: This might help a little, too: [Prolog. Structure(complex term) vs predicate, i dont really get the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972038/prolog-structurecomplex-term-vs-predicate-i-dont-really-get-the-difference/28972664#28972664)

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of such a predicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I fail to see why 5(X,Y) is syntactically not correct, while +(north,west) is correct.

A single digit is not an atom, but a number.

On page 33 section 2.1.1 Atoms and numbers it reads:

```
Atoms can be constructed in three ways:
1. Strings of letters, digits and the underscore character,  
     starting with a lower-case letter.
2. Strings of special characters such as + - * / < > = : . & _ ~
3. Strings of characters enclosed in single quotes.
```

The character `5`

- fails rule 1 because the string does not start with an underscore
  character or a lower-case letter
- fails rule 2 because it is not one
  of the special characters
- fails rule 3 because it is not enclosed
  in single quotes

The character `+` succeeds because by rule 2 it is a special character.

One way to explore this further is by using SWI-Prolog [functor/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=functor/3)

```
?- functor(+(north,west),Name,Arity).
Name =  (+),
Arity = 2.

?- functor(5(X,Y).
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: functor(
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: 5(X,Y) .
```

> what the exact difference is between a relation and a structure

On page 4 Section 1.1 Defining relations by facts

In general, a relation is defined as the set of all its instances. For example **parent(tom,bob)** is a particular *instance* of the **parent** relation. With other instances being:

```
parent(pam,bob)
parent(tom,liz)
parent(bob,ann)
parent(bob,pat)
parent(pat,jim)
```

On page 35 Section 2.1.3 Structures

**Structured objects** (or simply *structures*) are objects that have several components, e.g.

```
date(1, may, 2001)
point(1,1)
seg(P1,P2)
seg(point(1,1),point(2,3))
(a + b) * (c - 5)           % uses infix operator
*(+(a,b),-(c,5))            % uses prefix operator
```

Looking at your question makes me think you are looking for a property common to both relation and structure that can be used to distinguish one from the other. I don't know of one; when I think about using Prolog I don't think `should I use a relation or a structure`, I think of `how is the data structured` which can be as simple as a number or more complex as a structure or a structure of structures, and then `what are the predicates (rules) that are needed to reach a goal` given the data. In looking at the definitions given the best I can say is that a specific relation can be composed of many structures that have the same functor, but that is not an idea that will last in my mind past this period.

Comment: It gets a little fuzzy. For example, if I have two facts, `likes(john, mary).` and `likes(john, sue).`, `likes/2` does form a relation even though there's no rule. Also, to add more fuzziness, `add(X,Y,Z) :- Z is X + Y.` is equivalent to `:-( add(X, Y, Z), (Z is X+Y))` which could be considered a *structure*. Perhaps a *structure* is any compound term which one has associated a relational data meaning to (which them makes it also a *relation*?).

Comment: Yep, I wasn't trying to negate your answer as much as just add to the discussion.

Comment: @lurker No worries. If I know most of the answer I know that the comments will point out where I lack knowledge and then I learn something. Please keep commenting as it helps me learn. As I have the exact edition of the book I will look into this more.

Comment: @GuyCoder Thanks for your extensive clarification. I assume that it is correct to say then, that 'structure' and 'relationship' is just a different way of looking at the data in your database and simply a matter of terminology (as in, Prolog does not differentiate on a deeper level between the two)?

Comment: Personally I do not think of `relationship` as being data, I think of it more like algorithm. One way I think of Prolog is as a network of nodes and edges, the structure is how the nodes are connected and what is the template of a node, while a relationship is pattern that gets you from item of data in one node to another data item in another node. Continued.

Comment: So for parent the structure is a tuple (Figure 1.3) while for a math expression it is a tree (Figure 2.5). Parent is a relationship that get you from one person in one node to another person in another node, or `+`, `*`, `-`, is a relationship that gets you from one number to another number.

Comment: But is it correct to say that a relationship of the form `parent(X,Y)` is just a compound structure with functor `parent` and arguments `X` and `Y` ? Just as something of the form `date(1, may, 2001)` would be a compound structure with functor `date` and arguments `1` , `may` and `2001` ? And could we then inversely also speak of a relationship `day` in our database if something as `date(1, may, 2001)` would be present?

Comment: @milanv I personally don't have a problem with what you stated up to `?`. How is the relationship `day` defined?

Comment: I dug into some authoritative references and this is what I found. If this does not answer your questions then I have no more info. First Bratko leaves you wondering, so I checked the official Prolog spec (ISO/IEC 13211-1 : 1995(E)) and it does not use the word relationship. However, ["The Art of Prolog"](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/912229865) reads `Another name for a relation is a predicate` and ISO spec for predicate reads `An identifier together with an arity` @lurker gave you a good [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28972664/1243762).

Comment: If you still want more detail then the authoritative references I find of value are: 1. ISO/IEC 13211-1 : 1995(E) 2. ["The Art of Prolog"](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/837861643) 3. ["The Craft of Prolog"](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/856816459) 4. ["Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence"](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/805270490)

Comment: You can also find free Prolog books listed for the Prolog tag [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog/info) and I also like [Home Page of Markus Triska](https://www.metalevel.at/)

Comment: I did find this [Prolog Glossary](http://www2.dcs.hull.ac.uk/NEAT/dnd/AI/prolog_glossary.html) online. I'm not so sure it's authoritative, though. It includes the words *relation*, *fact*, and *structure*. Oddly, it doesn't include the word *term* as having a specific Prolog definition. A *term* would be a *structure*, or *atom* or *number*, etc. So a *structure* is a Prolog *term* that can is constructed of simpler *terms*. I think another term for this is *compound term*, which also, oddly, doesn't show up in the glossary.

Comment: If you want to dig beyond the colloquial words and into the inner workings then read up on [Horn clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause) and [SLD Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLD_resolution).